# JsonSyntaxException when parsing date with Retrofit/Gson

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

I want to use this service: http://fast-gorge.herokuapp.com/contacts
I set up Retrofit parsing like this:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
.setDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT)
.create();
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
.setEndpoint(BASE_URL)
.setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
.build();
apiService = restAdapter.create(PersonsServiceEndpointInterface.class);
```

where my date format is:

```
private static final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.ZZZ'Z'"
```

However when I run the app I got into the failure(RetrofitError error) method
with the message: retrofit.RetrofitError: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: 2014-07-31T07:49:23.000Z

Do you know what kind of pattern I have to use to parse the date in the Json body? I've tried lots of things but none of them worked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'`.

Comment: Oh so it's a miliseconds value? I thought it's time zone because of the 'Z' at the end. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.zzz'Z'"`